# Flask routing issues on CherryPy

Tags: python, routes, flask, cherrypy

I tried the method on http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/24/ to make Flask work on CheryPy server and It worked, no problem so far. But I can't route anything else but the "/". For example if I want to route to localhost/xyz, It returns "Hello World".

Should I create single Flask app for every single path?

the server.py is:

```
from cherrypy import wsgiserver
from qwe import app

d=wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({"/":app,"/xyz":app})
server=wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0',80),d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()
```

the qwe.py is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

@app.route("/xyz")
def ff():
    return "Test1"
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Please add as answer

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian removed and getting 404 now on localhost/xyz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work this way:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def root():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/xyz")
def xyz():
    return "Hello XYZ!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

server.py:

```
from cherrypy import wsgiserver
from app import app

d = wsgiserver.WSGIPathInfoDispatcher({'/': app})
server = wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 9999), d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        server.start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop()
```

go to `http://localhost:9999` and get `Hello World!` , then go to `http://localhost:9999/xyz` and get `Hello XYZ!`

Comment: It worked, thanks but why can't I make it useful for the port 80?

Comment: maybe another application is acting as a server on that port? Skype?